# update data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm a beginner in NodeJS and mongodB and I'm using mongoose and trying to update data of product using this code

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(DB_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => 
            feature = new FaeturesModel({
              name: featureName,
              description: featureDesc,
              catagory: featureCatagory,
              price: featurePrice + ' IQD' ,
              image: featureImage,
              dateOfCreation: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/')
            })).then(() => {
      return FaeturesModel.updateOne({"_id" : id} , {$set : {feature}})
            .then(()=> feature.save())
          .then(() => {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            resolve()
          }).catch(err => {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            reject(err)
          })
        }
      )
})}
```

the problem is that the record is added as a new one without deleting the old one

Answer (score 1):

Saving the document creates a new one.
If you want to update something:

```
await Model.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { name: 'foo' } })
```

Basically remove the `.then(()=> feature.save())` and it'll work.

This is from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html).

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to mention that when you're updating, you don't create a new document like this `new Feature()` instead you say:

```
Model.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: req.body }).then(res => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Because `new Feature()` creates a new document with a new `_id` attached to it, so you can't update the existing document.

Hope it's clear now :D

**EDIT 2**

This is not part of the question, but use

```
const schema = new Schema({
  ...
},
{ timestamps: true });
```

in your schema instead

```
dateOfCreation: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/')
```

It's easier to save creation date.

Comment: i removed it and gave me an error says 

Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id' and from the code above i didnt update the _id

Comment: Try to use ```req.body``` instead of ```new Feature()``` when you update.
So ```FaeturesModel.updateOne({"_id" : id} , {$set : {req.body}})```

Comment: thanx bro it worked and I'll post the code below

Answer (score 0):

````
exports.updateFeature = (id,featureName, featureCatagory, featurePrice , featureDesc , featureImage) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(DB_URL, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }).then(() => 
            feature =({
              name: featureName,
              description: featureDesc,
              catagory: featureCatagory,
              price: featurePrice + ' IQD' ,
              image: featureImage,
              dateOfCreation: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/')
            })).then(() => {
      return FaeturesModel.updateOne({'_id' : id} , {$set : feature})
            
          .then(() => {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            resolve()
          }).catch(err => {
            mongoose.disconnect();
            reject(err)
          })
        }
      )
})}```
````